# Spring creating own columns with wrong reference in table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have problem with "communication" between `Spring` and `PostgreSQL`.

My class `User.java`:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USERS";
public static final String SEQENCE = "USERS_SEQ";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQENCE, sequenceName = SEQENCE, allocationSize = 1)
private Long userId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Department department;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "organizazion_id")
private Organization organization;
```

Create table script for `USERS`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (
    USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    DEPARTMENT_ID BIGINT,
    ORGANIZATION_ID BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ORGANIZATION_ID) REFERENCES ORGANIZATION(ORGANIZATION_ID)
);
```

Class `Department.java`

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "DEPARTMENT";
public static final String SEQENCE = "DEPARTMENT_SEQ";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQENCE, sequenceName = SEQENCE, allocationSize = 1)
private Long departmentId;
private String departmentName;
.
.
. //Some other columns of primitive types about department..
```

Create table script for `DEPARTMENT`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEPARTMENT (
    DEPARTMENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (DEPARTMENT_ID)
);
```

Class Organization.java

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ORGANIZATION";
public static final String SEQENCE = "ORGANIZATION_SEQ";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQENCE, sequenceName = SEQENCE, allocationSize = 1)
private Long organizationId;
private String organizationName;
private String street;
private String postalCode;
private String state;
private String city;
```

Create table script for `ORGANIZATION`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORGANIZATION (
    ORGANIZATION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    ORGANIZATION_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    STREET VARCHAR(255),
    POSTAL_CODE VARCHAR(50),
    STATE VARCHAR(255),
    CITY VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ORGANIZATION_ID)
);
```

When I run the program, the `Spring` create "own" columns in `PostgreSQL`, and it's look like:

```
USER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, DEPARTMENT_DEPARTMENT_ID, ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_ID
```

How can I fix it ? It should be without columns

```
DEPARTMENT_DEPARTMENT_ID, ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_ID
```

The annotation `@Column(name = "column_name")` can't be used here.

Comment: Can you show the declarazion of department and organization?

Comment: @Jens here you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As join column you should reference the attribute in the other class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = SEQENCE, sequenceName = SEQENCE, allocationSize = 1)
private Long userId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "departmentId")
private Department department;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "organizazionId")
private Organization organization;
```